# Azure-Devops - a URL to see all the PRs I'm involved in?

Tags: user-interface, azure-devops, pull-request

In every ADO page there's a little checklist-icon button at the top next to the search field. The button expands to a pop-up which will show me all the PRs I'm currently involved in, across all repositories. Yay!  But I'm so exceedingly lazy that I'd like a single bookmarkable URL which shows me the same information. Anyone know of such a thing ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The URL is `https://dev.azure.com/<organization name>/_pulls`